# NamenotFoundException for entity manager factory JBoss EAP 6.3

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss-eap-6, seam2

I am using Seam 2.2, Hibernate 4 and JBOSS EAP 6.3. I have received the following error,

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: AmasterEntityManagerFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.AmasterEntityManagerFactory
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:103)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:243)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:241) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
... 168 more
```

In my **persistence.xml**

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/AmasterEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

In **components.xml**

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context  name="entityManager"
                                 auto-create="true"
                  persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:jboss/AmasterEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

Anyone faced this problem before? Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.

Instead of persistence-unit-jndi-name attribute I have added persistence-unit-name in the persistence:entity-manager-factory 
And instead of persistence-unit-jndi-name attribute added entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}"

```
<persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="AccountMaster"/>  
<persistence:managed-persistence-context  name="entityManager"
                                 auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seam 2.2 is only compatible with hibernate 3 (I think 3.6). 
According to [seam 2 Initialization, migration hibernate 3 to hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713546/seam-2-initialization-migration-hibernate-3-to-hibernate-4)  Seam 2.3 should be compatible with hibernate 4.

In our company environment, we had about 10 seam applications which also used seams persistence integration and wanted to use them on JBoss EAP 6. After spending weeks on the migration and struggling with a lot of issues, we decided to get rid of seam and migrated the applications to JSF.

Comment: jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name is not supported in AS 7 anymore, see the comments in: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have resolved the issue without using jndi name. Please check my answer.